# Swift Firebase Image UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase, uiactivityviewcontroller

Need help retrieving and setting an image from firebase. I am able to get the right URL for the image, but unsure on how to convert it to an actual picture I can share using the UIActivityViewController. "let titlePost = self.feeds[sender.tag].downloadURL" is what I am using to retrieve the specific image URL from a post from a tableview feed within my app. I have tried giving it a shot but need some help. Thank you

```
let shareAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Share", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in
        var objectsToShare: [AnyObject]?
        let image: UIImage?

        let titlePost = self.feeds[sender.tag].downloadURL

        if let postURL = URL(string: titlePost) {
            let postRequest = URLRequest(url: postURL)

            image.setImageWith(postURL, placeholderImage: nil, options: SDWebImageOptions.progressiveDownload, completed: { (imageRequest, imageResponse, error) -> Void in
                // failure downloading image
                print("Error downloading Firebase post image")
                print(error)
            })
        }

        objectsToShare = [titlePost as AnyObject]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare!, applicationActivities: nil)

        // present the view controller
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
```

**Where I am pulling the image from**

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "feedCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomerPostsViewCell {
        let post = feeds[indexPath.row]
        let caption = post.caption
        let downloadURL = post.downloadURL
        let name = post.name
        let address = post.address
        let state = post.state
        let date = post.date
        let distance = post.distance

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

        // Business Name
        cell.businessNameLabel.text = name
        cell.businessAddressLabel.text = address
        cell.businessStateLabel.text = state
        cell.businessPostDistanceLabel.text = distance

        // caption
        cell.captionView.text = caption

        // post image
        cell.businessPostImage.image = nil
        if let postURL = URL(string: downloadURL) {
            let postRequest = URLRequest(url: postURL)
            cell.businessPostImage.setImageWith(postURL, placeholderImage: nil, options: SDWebImageOptions.progressiveDownload, completed: { (imageRequest, imageResponse, error) -> Void in
                // failure downloading image
                print("Error downloading Firebase post image")
                print(error)
            })
        }

        // set date of post
        cell.postTimeLabel.text = dateString


        cell.optionsButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.optionsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(optionsButton), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}


// MARK: Queries
func getAllPosts(refreshing: Bool, refreshControl: UIRefreshControl?) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "businessName").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        //observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            self.feeds = []
            for item in dict {
                let json = JSON(item.value)
                let uid = json["uid"].stringValue
                var name: String = json["businessName"].stringValue
                let address: String = json["businessStreet"].stringValue
                let state: String = json["businessCity"].stringValue
                let caption: String = json["caption"].stringValue
                let downloadURL: String = json["download_url"].stringValue
                let timestamp = json["timestamp"].doubleValue
                let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp/1000)

                let lat = json["businessLatitude"].doubleValue
                let long = json["businessLongitude"].doubleValue
                let businessLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)

                let latitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
                let longitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
                let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

                let distanceInMeters: Double = userLocation.distance(from: businessLocation)
                let distanceInMiles: Double = distanceInMeters * 0.00062137
                let distanceLabelText = String(format: "%.2f miles away", distanceInMiles)

                self.uid = json["uid"].stringValue

                let usersReference = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users").queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: uid)
                usersReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                    if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                        let userInfo = dict.allValues[0]
                        let userJSON = JSON(userInfo)
                        name = userJSON["name"].stringValue

                    }
                    let post = Post(uid: uid, caption: caption, downloadURL: downloadURL, name: name, date: date, address: address, state: state, distance: distanceLabelText)


                    self.feeds.append(post)

                    // sort posts by date/distance
                    //self.feeds.sort {$0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedAscending}
                    self.feeds.sort {$0.distance.compare($1.distance) == .orderedAscending}
                    self.feedTableView.reloadData()

                })
            }
        }
        if refreshing {
            refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
        }
        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
    })
}
```

Comment: if you add `print(titlePost)` before `if let postURL` in above code, what does it print?

Comment: It print the URL to the image

Comment: Is this the correct url? and where is this method defined : `setImageWith(_:placeholderImage: options: completed:)` ?

Comment: No, I set a "tag" to the indexPath.row so I can pull the image from a "post". I have a feed of posts in a tableview is where I am pulling from.

Comment: I added the code where I am doing the firebase call and setting to cell. As you can see before "return cell" I have a "tag" set

Comment: Can you please tell where is this method defined : `setImageWith(_:placeholderImage: options: completed:)`, is this from a library?

Comment: No, that's just me trying to create the image. You can delete that. It was just an attempt

Comment: ok what is the type of `businessPostImage` is it `UIImage` or `UIImageView`?

Comment: If you look at my edit, I tried taking that code from where it says "cell.businessPostImage.image = nil"

Comment: What is underneath "cell.businessPostImage.image = nil" is what I am using to display the images in my cells

Comment: It is UIImageView

Comment: In your activitcontroller code you are using `let image: UIImage?` , may be that is the problem?

Comment: My problem is just trying to take the "downloadURL" and assigning it to "image" or something so then I can add it to UIActivityViewController

Comment: Do you have a solution on how to use the "downloadURL" and put it into a "image" that can be shared so I can give you credit for your help?